# Add row or column in a table with content then replace specific row/columns with new columns in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, replace, find, addition

I want to add new column in the end of the table with sepcific content in each row, and then replace speicif content of that new column if it matches this.
thanks.
This is the code, I didn't write this, i just added from different codes in one place.

For example, the code find of there is a text on the page with the name Product # 2 and add buy now button for Product # 2  below in Buy Row

Thanks

```js
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("#list_table");


[].forEach.call(allDivs, function(a) {


  if (/\bProduct # 1\b/gi.test(a.textContent)) {



    $("#list_table th:last-child").after('<th>Buy</th>');
    $("#list_table td:last-child").after('<a class="noinfo">N/A</a></td></a>');

  }







});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="40%" id="list_table" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>category</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product # 1</td>
      <td>category # 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product # 2</td>
      <td>category # 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Product # 3</td>
      <td>category # 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: matches this? in what way?

Comment: the product name, for example if there is Product # 2 then it replaces with buy now button and set its link to different url. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

don't forget to replace "#" with your action.

```js
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll("#list_table");
    [].forEach.call(allDivs, function(a) {
        if (/\bProduct # 1\b/gi.test(a.textContent)) {
            $("#list_table th:last-child").after('<th>Buy</th>');
            $("#list_table td:last-child").after('<td><a href="#" class="noinfo">N/A</a></td>');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table width="40%" id="list_table" border="1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>category</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product # 1</td>
          <td>category # 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product # 2</td>
          <td>category # 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Product # 3</td>
          <td>category # 3</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: but what about now if i want to link product # 2 to another different link default link which would be for each one?  Thanks